# Simplifying a SQL Server query with a shortcut

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where many columns could be blank or null. They actually have longer names than the example below which I am using as an example:

```
 select * 
 from table1 
 where field1 is not null and field1 != '' and
       field2 is not null and field2 != ''
 ...etc
```

It gets tiresome having to type

```
x is not null and x != ''.
```

Is there some way to specify "x is not null and x != ''"?

Like for Java with

```
StringUtils.isNotEmpty(x)
```

Comment: You can define an scalar function, that receives a field as parameter and returns a boolean value if the field is not null and not ''

Comment: You can create the where-clause in code using a loop. Put the field names into an array for this.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes do you have an example?

Comment: I talking about doing this on the front-end, in a programming language like C# or VB. I don't know what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
where isnull(x, '') <> ''
```

a lot. I find it a bit easier to "understand" than `nullif`.

--  EDIT  ---------------------------------------

I missed that they were all ANDed together. So, if all N fields must be non-null and not empty, assuming that all fields are strings (varchars), this should do it:

```
where isnull(field1 + field2 + field3 + ... + fieldN,  '') <> ''
```

First, the strings are concatenated together:

- If any are null, the result will be null
- If none are null and all are empty, the result will be an empty string
- Else, the result will be a non-empty string

Next, the results are `isnulled`:

- If the concatenated value is null, it is set to an empty string
- Else, you get the concatenated contents (empty or not-empty string)

Last, compare that with the empty string:

- If True, then either all are empty or one or more is null
- If False, none are null and at least one is not empty

Comment: Actually, I just tried the coalesce which did not work:

a b c d e coal
263757128 1790751055 NULL  229 263757128

The value "coal" is the coalesce of the other fields.

Comment: One bad thing about stack overflow is you can't edit the responses and format them nicely.  I hope you can read it.

Comment: Oh I see that is for at least one non-null field, not for all non null

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE NULLIF(field1, '') IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, I would use COALESCE for this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(field1, '') > ''
```

ISNULL also works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude rows where every field is null or blank you can do it like this:

```
WHERE COAlESCE(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,'') <> ''
```